# Return Records from 2nd Table if Query on First Table Returns No Records

Tags: sql-server

The goal is to return values for id_num and county from table address_master (address_master has one record per id) if BOTH an id_num AND county value is not returned using the following query on address_history:

`SELECT DISTINCT a.id_num, a.county
FROM address_history a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_num, MIN(archive_job_tim) AS MaxEnrollDate
            FROM address_history
            GROUP BY id_num) b
ON (a.id_num = b.id_num AND a.archive_job_tim = b.MaxEnrollDate)
WHERE addr_cde = '*LHP'`

Sample Data:

Table address_history (contains historical changes, multiple records per id are possible)

```
id_num | county | archive_job_tim
-------|--------|----------------
123    |012     |10/17/2001 10:48:38
123    |NULL    |10/17/2001 09:50:02
123    |042     |11/17/2003 08:22:01
134    |NULL    |12/10/2005 02:14:23
145    |534     |9/27/1996 00:00:00
```

Table address_master (contains only the most recent record for every id)

```
id_num | county | archive_job_tim
-------|--------|-----------------
123    |563     |12/22/2015 10:29:01
134    |734     |2/23/2005 07:21:15
145    |943     |10/22/1996 06:24:13
168    |012     |6/5/2017 08:01:22
197    |NULL    |7/1/2017 10:16:02
```

Query result should be:

```
id_num | county
-------|--------
123    |012    (because it is the earliest record with a county for this id in address_history)
134    |734    (because the only record(s) in address_history has no county, returns record from address_master)
145    |534    (because it is the earliest record with a county for this id in address_history)
168    |012    (because no record exists in address_history for this id)
197    |NULL   (because no record exists in address_history for this id)
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from
(
    Select *,'am' as Note from address_master
    union all
    Select *,'ah' as Note from address_history
) a where (a.Note = 'ah' and a.county is not null) or a.Note = 'am'
Order by Row_Number() over(partition by id_num order by archive_job_tim)
```

Output as below:

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+
| id_num | county |     archive_job_tim     | Note |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+
|    123 | 12     | 2001-10-17 10:48:38.000 | ah   |
|    134 | 734    | 2005-02-23 07:21:15.000 | am   |
|    145 | 534    | 1996-09-27 00:00:00.000 | ah   |
|    168 | 12     | 2017-06-05 08:01:22.000 | am   |
|    197 | NULL   | 2017-07-01 10:16:02.000 | am   |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kandasamy, but I'm getting an error as I try and use this in the Command text in an Excel connection (where I usually plug in SQL for generating connected tables).  It says:   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: Updated query as one parenthesis missing in over()

Comment: Thank you.  The query is generating results now, however, it is only returning rows from address_master, and there are records for many id numbers in address_history that should be resulting.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output data?

Comment: Thank you.  Yes.  I've added sample input and output data above.  I tried to post it in table format as indicated in SOF editing help, but it didn't come out looking like a table...I apologize.

Comment: I meant to say that the input and output are in readable table format now.  I still have not been able to figure out the query itself for the desired result.  Google has not been much help on this issue :(

Comment: Updated with query can you check now?

Comment: This worked great!  I made a few further customizations to get it worked out just right and it is perfect.  I can see what you did and I'm excited to use this for some future solutions as well.  Thank you Mr. Kandasamy :D

Comment: Thanks and happy coding